# C# reading a byte array as a string

Tags: c#

I am coding in c#.
I need to read the string of bytes without converting.

bytes: `68`
string: `44`

I want to be able to convert it through code

---

I figured it out

```
#region "Grab Bytes Function"
private string grabBytes(byte[] buffer)
{
    byte[] bytes = buffer;
    string output = string.Empty;
    foreach (byte item in bytes)
    {
            output += Convert.ToString(item, 16).ToUpper().PadLeft(2, '0');
    }
    return output;
}
#endregion
#region "Grab String Function"
private string grabString(byte[] buffer)
{
    byte[] bytes = buffer;
    string output = string.Empty;
    foreach (byte item in bytes)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
        {
            if (grabBytes(new byte[] { item }) == grabBytes(new byte[] { byte.Parse(i.ToString()) }))
                output += item + ".";
        }
    }
    string output1 = output.Remove(output.Count() - 1, 1);
    if (output1 != "0.0.0.0")
        return output1;
    else
        return "";
}
#endregion
```

Comment: are the bytes stored in a string or a byte[].  if that's the case you just need t o convert it: `var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(result);`.  If it's in a string you'll need to parse the string and then convert.

Comment: that doesn't work, it just gets the string. and i figured it out

Comment: thanks for the polite response for attempting to help you.

Comment: The input `68E6C046` looks like a `Hex` value, Have you tried anything? Is it possible to show some code instead for this input and output spec.

Comment: i just posted up my code but i can probably simplify it so it runs smoother and Gary I am sorry if I offended you and thanks for the help.

Comment: The decimal equivalent of 0x68E6C046 is 1759952966, not 10412928130. What are your trying to accomplish? Sorry but your code is so bad it hurts.

Comment: Didn't you actually mean to write `output += i + "."` instead of `output += item + "."` ?

Comment: yes i meant to put item + "." so it writes the byte then a . in front of it

Comment: Then your function `grabBytes` serves absolutely no purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is equivalent to this one:

```
private string grabString(byte[] buffer)
{
  var asDecimal = string.Join(".", buffer));
  return (asDecimal == "0.0.0.0" ? "" : asDecimal);
}
```